# VStudioCode debugging of React fails to launch

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

I have the following `launch.json` for my project:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to Chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "type": "chrome",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "python": "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/TCDigitalProject/TCDigitalBackend/TCDigitalVenv/bin/python",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/TCDigitalBackend/TCDigital/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "--noreload"
            ],
            //"args": ["create_init_data"],
            "django": true
        }
    ]
}
```

The debugging of *Python-Django* works handsomely, but debug of *Attach to Chrome* fails with the following error:

[image]

I also observed that my debug configurations list has two entries for `Attach to Chrome` (one postfixed with the name of the project) but when I chose the postfixed one, it changes to the other one automatically:

[image]

I also get this error when I make any change to `launch.json`:

```
The mypy daemon executable ('dmypy') was not found on your PATH. Please install mypy or adjust the mypy.dmypyExecutable setting.
```

This is the main directories tree for my project:

[image]

I don't know how to solve this.